# Did Helios Flight 522 take off with its pressurisation mode selector in manual?

Tags: boeing-737, accident-investigation, cabin-pressure

I'm currently doing a write up on the Helios Flight 522 disaster. Full disclosure, this is a journalistic piece, and I'm not an aviation expert.

I'm many hours in at this point and most of it so far has made sense. The pilots missed the pressurisation mode selector being set to manual in pre-flight and take off checks, and then did not recognise and/or react appropriately the horn that went off in the cockpit. This resulted in rapid onset hypoxia, which incapacitated the pilots leading to the crash.

My problem is this. Alan Irwin, the ground engineer who was performed the pressurisation leak check before Flight 522 took off says that he in fact DID leave the switch in AUTO. In a recent [Guardian article](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2020/sep/19/in-2005-helios-flight-522-crashed-into-a-greek-hillside-was-it-because-one-man-forgot-to-flip-a-switch), he says:

> "Except that it was not left in manual, says Irwin, who argues that investigators had not accounted for the distorting effects of impact."

and,

> "Irwin’s explanation for the crash is that the system that controlled the outflow valve failed. But, of course, there was no proof either way."

So Alan is saying "hey, I left that switch in AUTO, and it was knocked to manual on the impact of the crash."

But, in page 66 of the Helios Flight 522 [accident investigation report](https://reports.aviation-safety.net/2005/20050814-0_B733_5B-DBY.pdf), it states that:

> The NVM recording showed that on the accident flight, the cabin pressure control system was being operated in the manual mode.

So, according to the accident report, there *is* proof from the NVM recording that the switch was in manual BEFORE the flight crashed.

**On a 737-31S, does the flight data recorder have a datapoint for the position of the pressurization mode selector? Cam we say with certainty that this plane DID NOT take off with the pressurisation mode selector in AUTO?**

Why is Alan, a competent ground engineer who by all accounts seems to be very well-trusted, well-like and without incident throughout his career, saying that he thinks Helios Flight 522 crashed because 'the system that controlled the outflow valve failed'?

I also read the following in the accident report, page 102 (obviously this is referring to another earlier incident that took place on the accident plane):

> On 16 December 2004, Helios Airways flight HCY 535 was en route from Warsaw, Poland, to Larnaca, Cyprus, cruising at FL350 at position EVENO, just prior to the top of descent to Larnaca, when the aircraft experienced a rapid decompression. The cabin altitude warning horn sounded and the cabin altitude went up rapidly. The passenger oxygen masks deployed automatically.

Okay, flight 522 didn't rapidly depressurise, it was never pressurised in the first place. But they go on to say:

> The Air Accident and Incident Investigation Board (AAIIB) of Cyprus was not able to
> reach a conclusive decision as to the causes of the incident, but indicated two
> possibilities:
> “a) An electrical malfunction caused the opening of the outflow valve; and
> b) An inadvertent opening of the aft service door with the handle not in the closed
> position.”

Is this what Alan is referring to? Can anyone help me make sense of this?

Comment: Welcome to Aviation.SE! I'm afraid your first question is opinion-based, which is off topic according to the [help center](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). We cannot say why Alan Irwin said what he said.

Comment: Basically, what @Bianfable said. The only non-opinionated thing we can do is point you to the relevant parts of the official accident report - which you seem to already have.

Comment: Hmmm, that's fair. I guess I don't really know what I'm asking in a technical sense. I just wonder if it's a possibility that the pilots set off with the pressurisation mode selector in 'auto', but then switched it to manual when it became apparent that - as Alan claims - the system that controlled the outflow valve failed? The AAIIB states this very thing may have happened on the same plane. Or at least they think it may have happened.

Comment: I agree this is opinion based. He could be lying to try and avoid blame, or he could be right, or wrong in a different way. There's simply no way to give a definite answer. As for whether things are possible, thousands of hours went into the accident report, I can't see us adding technical insight.

Comment: My understanding is that it was actually NOT part of the SOP for the Ground Engineer to switch the pressurisation mode selector back to AUTO in any instance. You're right though, it could simply be him trying to rid himself of guilt. Still, I can't help but wonder if the NVM recording can show only that the pressurisation mode selector was being operated on manual mode at SOME POINT during the flight, but not whether or not the flight actually took with the pressurisation mode selector in MAN.

Comment: A non opinionated question might be "On a 73-[model in question] does the flight data recorder have a datapoint for the position of the pressurization mode selector".

Comment: Okay, no problem. I'll change it so it complies with rules.

Comment: The answer is on page 115 of the report. Sorry, I'm not sure how to delete this thread.

Comment: @NickBird No need to delete, you can post an answer to your own question.

Comment: The mis-positioning of a switch by ground crew should NOT have any bearing on an accident like this.  Before start, the Capt does a "flow" where all switches and controls are checked for proper positioning in a standardized tactile pattern, then the checklist is read through while visually confirming everything done during the flow.  There is no excuse for the flight crew not noticing that a switch was at the wrong position and even if the tech left a switch at MAN instead of AUTO, he is not to blame for anything.

Comment: I agree, and even the report agrees - it is absolutely the responsibility of the flight crew. Alan and his team were scape goats.